# Create a Wireless Link between 8 nodes in ns3

Tags: ns-3

I have to build a topology with 8 nodes that are connected via the wifi network. How to generate the output graph.

In ns-3 I can't find examples to do so.

How could I build the topology ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: No i dint tried any thing@ David

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, go through the documentation available on the nsnam website: https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.26/tutorial/ns-3-tutorial.pdf

The programs *first.cc*, *second.cc* .. *seventh.cc* pretty much cover most of the fundamentals. These programs will also help you understand how to create a topology involving links built on Ethernet, Wifi and all kinds of protocols. The link to the documentation above is an excellent one and neatly describes how to get started with ns3.

Oh and just in case you don't know where to find these programs, this is the directory:

/ns-allinone-3.26/ns-3.26/examples/tutorial/